# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in cmd

Tags: java

I am facing this problem while trying to run my java file by writing java filename ....

I have read on many pages the possible ways this could be corrected but unfortunately I have been unable to correct my problem...

1. First of all I looked at my environment variables and observed that there was no **CLASSPATH**     set and I had pointed **PATH** correctly to my jre as well as jdk bin in C:\
2. Second I am able to run ***javac filename.java*** and observe that .class file gets built in the  local directory.
3. While writing **javac -classpath . filename** works writing **java -classpath . filename** (without .class) results in the same error.

I just don't know how to run my program in command prompt!!!!
Please do not give me links to the pages which have given the same answers that I have mentioned above as they do not work in my case.....

Please help....

Comment: Is your class in a package (i.e. uses the "package x.y.z" decl at the start of the file)?

Comment: I suggest you provide a SSCCE together with the exact output of your commands.

Comment: "Short, Self Contained, Correct Example"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if your class resides in some package `mypackage`, you need to make sure the class file is inside `mypackage/` and do

```
java -classpath . mypackage.YourClass
```

Comment: the default package is discouraged. Place it in some package.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit little information in your post ... as said, a complete example would really help solving this. Some ideas:

- Is class named `filename`? If not, you should make sure to call the right class name in the java command.
- if you have strange characters in your class name (basically anything apart from A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _), it could be mangled by your file system and thus lead to `java` not being able to find it. Make sure that the class name is the same as the file name.
- If you use packages, make sure the package names are congruent to your file structure (see latest questions with tag package for some examples).
- Is your class public? If not, make it so. (This should give another error, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Stating javac filename.java and java filename are not enough for this really.

We also need to know the contents of the filename.java or at least the first few lines.

**This is the expected way to declare a class**

```
 public class Filename {
    }
```

**This is the way it would have to be to work given your example: java filename**

```
 public class filename {
    }
```

**This is could exist too, but you are probably just messing with us :)**

```
public class SomethingElse {
}
```

Overall no matter what the filename is on the filesystem, the class has a name and that is the name that the java command is expecting. I would recommend using the upper case first letter form as it is clearer imo